# Creating a restful Login API

Tags: wordpress, rest, oauth, restful-authentication, hmac

I have read a few articles on the subject, but I am just looking for some more advice really.

I have a WordPress site with a login functionality and user database on that site.

What I need to do is allow a 3rd party application to authenticate details which it receives against my WordPress database.

I was thinking the best way to do this would be by sending the data to a REST API, but security wise I cannot think how I can return a successful login without this being easily duplicated by a user.

I have read about oAuth and HMAC, but am not sure which route I should be going down.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides the XML-RPC API for this stuff. That's what the iPad/iPhone apps use.

Check out the Codex.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending
- http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API

For more general info, there's the Wikipedia entry, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC.

Comment: Thanks, I am still not sure whether that will be what I am looking for. I don't want the 3rd party application to be able to amend anything on my WordPress site. I just need them to post login details and then I will return a success message saying whether or not that user is valid. It is this success message that I am not sure about as I feel like it could be easily replicated.

Comment: If the app has a username and password then it can already do anything that the user can do.

Comment: Yeh it won't matter that they can do something. But it is validating for the 3rd party application that I am looking for

Comment: I don't understand in your first comment you 'don't want the 3rd part application to be able to amend anything' then it 'won't matter that they can do something'.

Comment: See this, it may be similar to what your trying to achieve.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39473/custom-xmlrpc-method-plus-authentication-of-user-woocommerce-order